# Angular: http RxJS dependant http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular14, rxjs7

I am developing a small app with Angular 14.1. I need to create a service that get information from N endpoint and is
dependant of an endpoint. I need a solution that could retrieve previous information fast as possible. This data will be
consumed by a component.

Extended information:

Current service is required to request information from HTTP endpoint that return some data like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "documents":[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "document 1",
      "type": "a"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "document 2"
      "type": "b"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "document 3"
      "type": "a"
    }
  ]
}
```

With previous response:

1. I need to filter all documents that their type are "a"
2. I need for each "id" create a new HTTP request to another endpoint to get more information. Return some data like this:

   ```
   {
       "name": "document 1",
       "type": "a",
       "start": "2022-10-10"
   }
   ```
3. I need to get a class instance for previous data.

I tried different ways that I think that are too dirty. Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using forkJoin. You already have an answer with an example, forkJoin is a ceational RxJS operator that creates an `Observable[]` and emits when all the `Observable` in the array have emitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just a combination of `concatMap` and a `forkJoin()` that will make all the inner requests concurrently:

```
getDocuments()
  .pipe(
    concatMap(response => {
      const documents = response.documents.filter(doc => doc.type === 'a');
      return forkJoin(documents.map(doc => otherRequest(doc)));  
    },
  )
```